# In ASP.NET Core, how to use sqlite

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I tried to create a rest api . when I try to change

```
 services.AddDbContext<WebContext>(options =>

   options.useSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebContext")));
```

when I try to do this I get this error. I installed sqlite nuget.and also Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore but I still got the problem

> error CS1061: 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition
>   for 'UseSqlite' and no extension method 'UseSqlite' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: I try to connect xamarin forms mobile app with a web page

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/7486 (found by Googling for your error message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
...
services.AddDbContext<WebContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebContext")));
...
```

And you also need to install the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` nuget package.